# setImageDrawable dont work with URL

Tags: android, url, imageview, drawable

i want to set Images from Url into an imageView. For testing I took some pictures into drawable folder.

```
//creat a list of images and put images inside
    final int[] imageList = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_test_img_1, R.drawable.ic_test_img_2, R.drawable.ic_test_img_3,
            R.drawable.ic_test_img_4, R.drawable.ic_test_img_5, R.drawable.ic_test_img_6};

    //for each picture into the list...
    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {

        //set RelativeLayout
        final RelativeLayout relView = new RelativeLayout(this);
        //set Params for the RelativeLayout
        relView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((windowWidth - 80), windowHeight - 80));
        relView.setX(40);
        relView.setY(40);
        relView.setTag(i);
        //set BackgroundColor RelativeLayout
        relView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        //set ImageView
        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
        //set the image from the list into the imageView
        img.setImageResource(imageList[i]);
        //set params to RelativLayout
        img.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((windowWidth), windowHeight));
        //show image
        relView.addView(img);
```

That works great. Now I want to set images from an ArrayList of URLs. I wrote this code:

```
//for each picture into the list...
    for (int i = 0; i < imageUrl.size(); i++) {

        //set RelativeLayout
        final RelativeLayout relView = new RelativeLayout(this);
        //set Params for the RelativeLayout
        relView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((windowWidth - 80), windowHeight - 80));
        relView.setX(40);
        relView.setY(40);
        relView.setTag(i);
        //set BackgroundColor RelativeLayout
        relView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        //set ImageView
        final ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
        //set the image from the list into the imageView

        final String url = imageUrl.get(i);

        new Thread() {

            public void run () {
                URL myUrl = null;
                try {
                    myUrl = new URL(url);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = (InputStream)myUrl.getContent();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
                img.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            }
        }.start();

        //set params to RelativLayout
        img.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((windowWidth), windowHeight));
        //show image
        relView.addView(img);
```

This code didn't work. There are no pictures inside the imageView. What is wrong with the Code?

Comment: Could it be that you get any exceptions, can you post the logs?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or any other image loading library and save yourself all that headache

and it's as easy as that

```
Glide.with(this).load("http://googl.com/gEgYUd").into(imageView);
```

Comment: no Glide creates it's own thread and caches the image for you. 
Glide is awesome

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I used  
            final ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
            final String url = imageUrl.get(i);
            Glide.with(this).load(url).into(img);
but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I put a println into the loop, but i don't get a log. I think there is another problem. I will debug my code and write you soon.

Comment: ok, i got the log. It look like this: falsefalsehttps://signup.euw.leagueoflegends.com/theme/signup_new_theme/img/logo-lol-smaller.png

what is this false mean and how i can remove this from my string?

Comment: where imageUrl data come from.
and when I remove the falsefalse prefix of the URL it's still invalid URL.

Comment: The imageUrl comes from a Twitter SearchQuery. The SearchQuery runs in a thread. In this thread i put the urls into the ArrayList imgURL. 

QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
                    for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
                        twitter4j.MediaEntity [] media = status.getMediaEntities();
                        for (twitter4j.MediaEntity m : media) {
                            imageUrl.add(m.getMediaURL());
                        }

Answer (score 0):

You need to use runOnUiThread method in Thread it will update imageview

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
                img.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            }
        });
```